# Using ezBoot() to get a bootstrapped mixed ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to bootstrap a mixed effects ANOVA. I have a fixed effect with two levels and a within-subjects factor with two conditions.

I though the ezBoot() function in R might work, and i can get this to work:

```
an2=ezBoot(data=data, wid=pps, dv=latency2, within=Condition, between=BREED, resample_within=FALSE, iterations=1e3)
```

But i am not sure how to go from there and get the ANOVA results.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Alternatively, would this be possible in another program like STATA (i know SPSS can't seem to do it...)

Comment: try using ezPerm instead, it is my understanding that bootstrapping is appropiate to calculate confidence intervals, whereas permutation test (`ezPerm`) to test hypothesis.

Comment: Also, I don't know if it is possible to jump to ANOVA results but if you look into the documentation (`?ezBoot`) they will show you how to plot the results with ezPlot2